# Is Google Pay PayPal depreceated?

Tags: paypal, google-pay

So my problem is, PayPal suggested a request type that is depreceated, and I don't know what API to use so my integration with Google Pay works with Paypal. This is the api PayPal suggested: [Google Pay Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create) . The API returns this:

```
`{
"name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
"message": "An internal service error has occurred",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
"debug_id": "41a6f4507a2df"
 }`
```

body is this:

```
` {
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "funding_instruments": [
        {
            "credit_card_token": {
                "credit_card_id": "CARD-1MD19612EW4364010KGFNJQI",
                "external_customer_id": "joe_shopper408-334-8890"
            }
        }
    ],
    "payer_info": {
        "email": "sb-coy8y5423854@personal.example.com",
        "payer_id": "AR6cGL6IXfI_BwzZGeBcpES7ilv1FZqJlYeMr3TZnp-07woQCczOi1oTjiiz4HQLqQgrMVPE6Ng2QafR"
    }
},
"transactions": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "total": "30.11",
            "currency": "USD",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "30.00",
                "tax": "0.07",
                "shipping": "0.03",
                "handling_fee": "1.00",
                "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
                "insurance": "0.01"
            }
        },
        "description": "The payment transaction description.",
        "invoice_number": "48787589673",
        "payment_options": {
            "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
        },
        "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "hat",
                    "description": "Brown hat.",
                    "quantity": "5",
                    "price": "3",
                    "tax": "0.01",
                    "sku": "1",
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                {
                    "name": "handbag",
                    "description": "Black handbag.",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "price": "15",
                    "tax": "0.02",
                    "sku": "product34",
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            ],
            "shipping_address": {
                "recipient_name": "Brian Robinson",
                "line1": "4th Floor",
                "line2": "Unit #34",
                "city": "San Jose",
                "country_code": "US",
                "postal_code": "95131",
                "phone": "011862212345678",
                "state": "CA"
            }
        }
    }
],
"note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://yourwebsite.com/return",
    "cancel_url": "https://yourwebsite.com/cancel"
}
```

} `

Any tips in what request I should use? I'm making the test with a credit card token because my country doesn't have google pay and paypal suport. But I need the PayPal API that accepts Google Pay direct token.

**Edit:**

I used [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/googlepay-integration/) and it informs this API url: api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

But it always returns the error described. The V2 request is totally different and don't have support (in the payments) for capture. Need a diferent paypal api request but I don't know what to use.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the version 2 of the same thing, as it suggests?

Comment: Have you followed this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/googlepay-integration/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I used the guide and it informs this API link https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment  but it always returns the error i described. The V2 request is totally different and don't have support (in the payments) for capture. Idk what API to use, I'm testing the v2/orders/ right now